# best approach to execute a dynamic query inside a SP

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I'm having some trouble executing a dynamic query inside my SP, and I thought asking for some help as I can't execute it correctly no matter what I try:

I have tried:

```
SET @subWorksQuery = 
'UPDATE JK_SubscriberWorks SET ' +
'update_date = convert(datetime, ''' + @dateNow + ''', 103), ' +
'challenge_' + convert(nvarchar(2), @challengeDay) + '_q = ''' + @challengeQuestion + ''', ' +
'challenge_' + convert(nvarchar(2), @challengeDay) + '_a = ''' + @challengeAnswer + ''' ' +
'WHERE subscriberwork_id = '' + convert(nvarchar(10), @subscriberWorksId) + '';';

execute @execReturn = @subWorksQuery
```

but I always get:

> Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_InsertChallengeResponse_test,
>   Line 112
>   The name 'UPDATE JK_SubscriberWorks SET update_date = convert(datetime, '23-12-2011 23:35:17', 103), challenge_23_q =
>   'Hvilket år blev Klasselotteriet omdannet til et aktieselskab? 
> **Få hjælp til svaret.**',
>   challenge_23_a = '1992' WHERE subscriberwork_id = ' +
>   convert(nvarchar(10), @subscriberWorksId) + ';' is not a valid
>   identifier.

Removing the UPDATE statement from that error and **run it independently**, it runs and performs the update

---

If I use `sp_executesql` like

```
SET @subWorksQuery = 
N'UPDATE JK_SubscriberWorks SET ' +
'update_date = @a, ' +
'challenge_' + convert(nvarchar(2), @challengeDay) + '_q = @b, ' +
'challenge_' + convert(nvarchar(2), @challengeDay) + '_a = @c ' +
'WHERE subscriberwork_id = @d;';

SET @parmDefinition = N'@a datetime, @b nvarchar(250), @c nvarchar(500), @d decimal';

execute sp_executesql 
             @subWorksQuery,
             @parmDefinition,
             @a = @CreateDate, @b = @challengeQuestion, @c = @challengeAnswer, @d = @subscriberWorksId;
```

It never performs the UPDATE, but does not throw any error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: USE SQL Query Analyzer and modify your first example to do PRINT @subWorksQuery. Now cut and paste the output of that PRINT statement into Query Analyzer and see if it is formed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it like this:

```
execute (@subWorksQuery)
```

[you won't be getting anything back from the update statement in the variable, and you can't run like this `execute (@execReturn = @subWorksQuery)` ]

Without parentheses it seems to be starting parsing, assuming it is a stored procedure name, but failing when it hits the max length for one.

In saying that, it is better to use [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) with parameters.

Comment: but in my 2nd example I do use `sp_executesql` but I never get it to update, and no error is been thrown...

Comment: @balexandre - Presumably nothing matches the `WHERE` clause then.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for in the return value, but if you just need the count of rows affected, that should be easy to obtain.

Change:

```
execute @execReturn = @subWorksQuery
```

to:

```
execute (@subWorksQuery)
select @execReturn = @@ROWCOUNT
```

Answer (score 0):

just a thought...your @d parameter is a decimal value. Is your id an int? is there a possible data type conflict?

how are your sp input parameters defined? Could you post the full sp?

Dave

Comment: my `@d` is decimal as PK is decimal as well